# crop product images but keep product centered and image height/width the same (batch, linux, cli)

Tags: woocommerce, debian, imagemagick, crop, mogrify

I'm taking photos of product I'm planning to sell in WooCommerce. I'm just starting out and for now I'm taking them with my mobile phone using a tripod and photocube. The quality and lighting are all fine.

Right now it seems that I haven't been able to keep my tripod distance the same for each image and therefore the object can be slightly smaller or larger than the others.

What I'd like is a command using something like imagemagick or mogrify to (auto)crop the images so the height and width of the actual object is the same for all images assuming the product are of similar sizes in real life as well.

Then add a little whitespace around the object so the height and width are the same for each image. This way Woocommerce will display them nicely on the catalog page.

Right now it's a bit of a mess. Some product have too much whitespace in a certain area which results in misalignment of titles and a bad overall look of the page.

also (as if I haven't made it difficult enough) it's important that the whitespace **underneath** the image must be the same for all images because the object in the images have to be level with other objects next to it.

I have 4200 images that need this and I would really appreciate any help. I use debian and prefer a batch command or app.

Comment: Kind of hard without seeing a few good ones and a few bad ones...

Comment: maybe I can simplify my goal. Autocrop > Add a certain amount of whitespace underneath > Then add whitespace left/right/top until certain image size is met.

Comment: Kind of hard without seeing some images and knowing sizes and certain things you haven't provided.

Comment: imagine an image of the side of a shoe... The width of a shoe is pretty much the same at all times, especially after applying autocrop. I think I got it figured out though, just need to test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't provided an image, I have faked one here, with a yellow border. I will do what I think you are asking but using magenta and cyan so you can see the effect - so you will need to replace those colours with white.

[image]

First, trim the current border:

```
convert start.png -trim 1.png
```

[image]

Now add a 100px fixed height strip across the bottom:

```
convert 1.png -background magenta -gravity south -splice x100 2.png
```

[image]

Now pad left, right and top, but not bottom to a standardised size:

```
convert 2.png -gravity south -background cyan -extent 500x500 3.png
```

[image]

Of course, you can do all that in one go:

```
convert start.jpg -trim                            \
   -background magenta -gravity south -splice x100 \
   -gravity south -background cyan -extent 500x500 result.png
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks a lot. It was exactly what I needed.

Comment: What if I wanted to do autocrop (trim), then only add a top and bottom border, so each shoe and shoe type is vertically aligned, yet the image height for each image is the same ?

Comment: Try `convert input.png -fuzz 10% -trim -bordercolor red -border 0x50 result.jpg`

Comment: That looks like what I need but I don't know the border size beforehand cause each image has a different height after trimming. Can't I use -extent to define the max height while keeping the object centered ?

Comment: notice how the total width and height are the same for each image regardless of the object dimensions. I need a batch command for this for all 4000+ images I have. You can omit the trimming cause my background burner service will trim them.

Comment: So, I assume you know the final height? If so, just set the final height (via `-extent`) and leave the width unaltered... `convert input.png -gravity center -background yellow -extent x200 result.png`